# Share cache between Grails and Java app or not?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, spring-integration, spring-data-jpa

we have a RESTful Java server built with Spring Roo (database reverse engineering), Social, Security, Integration (using several inbound-gateways to map the requested urls), Data JPA, embedded Groovy, etc...

Now we want to build a new backoffice upon Grails and we don't know how to manage the caching between both apps.

**Build separate domains**

In this case, we would have two independent projects and need to know how to share cache between grails and Java apps.

The Java app uses Hibernate 4 as ORM and eChache for caching spring methods so we think it must be some way to share the cache since GORM is hibernate-based. Any ideas?

**Build shared domain**

In this case we would build common domain and persistence groovy layers (as spring roo seems to be stuck) to be accesed by both apps.

The problem here would be to use this groovy classes into a Java project. We have think about migrating the app RESTful server to Grails but don't know whether the Spring Projects behaviour would be affected or not.

Which would be the best approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to share the cache?

Comment: Because changes in old backoffice are very common (add events, configuration changes, etc.) and are not being detected by the Java app many times. Sharing, any change in the backoffice should be automatically detected by the Java app and we could have more control over what objects need to be cached, which object need to be deleted from cache, etc.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I really don't see any reason why to share the cache. Why don't just take a database as a common building brick of both old and new back office apps and leave the caching on Hibernate for each of the apps separately? Cache should be a transparent (not controlled by application code) layer serving just for lowering a load on database.